# Screen tearing on google chrome in 15.10

Tags: drivers, xorg, google-chrome, intel-graphics, tearing

I am having problems with screen tearing while watching videos on google chrome (both with and without fullscreen). I have integrated Intel HD graphics controller on my Z97X-Gaming-5 motherboard. I have tried following things so far to deal with this problem:

1. Install [Intel graphics installer 1.4.0](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-installer-linux-1.4.0) and update drivers using it.
2. Disabled backing store option in xorg [using "-bs" option](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1278012). This solved the problem for Kodi and firefox but not for google chrome.
3. Added "TearFree" option to 20-intel.conf file as per [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/667466/screen-tearing-in-ubuntu-with-nvidia-intel-graphics) answer.
4. Disabled "Unredirect full screen windows" option in compiz settings manager.

None of these solutions have solved screen tearing in google chrome for me. Is there anything else that I can try? I have rebooted my machine after trying each of these solutions. I even tried reinstalling google chrome but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: Have you ensured that hardware acceleration is enabled in chrome's advanced settings? In _Additional Drivers_ in Ubuntu, is the Intel microcode enabled?

Comment: Enabling hardware acceleration solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [dobey](https://askubuntu.com/users/50737/dobey), enabling hardware acceleration in google chrome's advanced settings solved the problem.