# Screen tearing in portrait orientation only (Ubuntu 16.04, Intel HD Graphics)

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel, tearing

OS: Ubuntu LTS 16.04
PC: FullHD monitor, Intel HD Graphics 530, no external videocard

In landscape orientation all is good. 
In portrait orientation I have screen tearing problem, like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_tearing
When I move some small window across the screen, screen image tears in random horizonal lines.

I tried this (as someone suggested in similar questions):

```
sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

After reboot problem changes: now when I move small window across the screen, I clearly see tearing in only one same vertical (!) line at the right (at around 800px of 1080px screen width, didn't meaasure correctly). So I reverted this and installed xserver-xorg-video-intel again.

Also tried this solution:
[Screen tearing in Ubuntu with Nvidia/Intel graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/667466/screen-tearing-in-ubuntu-with-nvidia-intel-graphics)
But after creating /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf sytem won't boot.

Comment: An important comment under that question says "Note that since 10.10 the config file directory is now `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d` (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config)."

Comment: Yes, I tried /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d, thanks for correction. After this during os boot monitor lost signal.

Comment: @ukrbublik can you take a picture?

Comment: I have a video (https://youtu.be/sHfYKgsF2_I), it's when I uninstalled xserver-xorg-video-intel

Comment: And a photo (http://oi65.tinypic.com/16k5qvc.jpg) when xserver-xorg-video-intel is installed

Comment: Also I did mistake saying about "horizonal lines", they are always vertical, with or without "xserver-xorg-video-intel" installed. And sorry for vertical youtube video :) <br> Also I tried to add "20-intel.conf" and uninstall "xserver-xorg-video-intel" - in this case system boots, but no affect on tearing problem. With "xserver-xorg-video-intel" installed and "20-intel.conf" there is no video signal on monitor.

Comment: No suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I solved this - on Ubuntu / Pop OS 20.04

Enable Wayland by editing the file `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`

Change

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

To

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

Reboot. When you log in, make sure to choose "Wayland" as part of your Desktop environment.

My rotated screen doesn't tear!

Comment: indeed, switching to Wayland solved this issue on my Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

Using Wayland has solved this issue for me as well. I am using a Thinkpad T470 with integrated graphics and an Ubuntu 20.04 installation. I tried many solution to solve the tearing issue, but only this one worked. Side note - I am using an external monitor connected to the Thunderbolt port. Another thing I had to do was to comment out all the lines in

```
/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/61-gdm.rules
```

albeit I could probably leave the Nvidia line in my case.