# xserver-xorg-video-intel packages have unmet dependencies

Tags: drivers, graphics, xorg, dependencies, intel-graphics

i recently noticed screen tearing on my laptop with ubuntu-mate 16.04

an answer suggested to check if `xserver-xorg-video-intel` is installed or not.

but when i `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel` i get

```
exillustx@exillustx-laptop:~$ sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
[sudo] password for exillustx: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xserver-xorg-video-intel : Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.17.99.902)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

however i fixed screen tearing using [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/668590/699506), but i'm having another issue after this fix, lets say when i right click on a selected text, and then i hover on an item (e.g i hover on **paste** item ), sometimes it gets missing.

but i'm wondering why do i get unmet dependencies and i'm having another issue after fixing screen tearing? how do i fix this?

my system informations:

Release 16.04.2 LTS (Xenial Xerus) 64-bit
Kernel Linux 4.10.0-27-generic x86_64
MATE 1.12.1
Memory: 3.8 GiB
Processor: Intel® Pentium(R) CPU N3540 @ 2.16GHz × 4

Comment: This is a wrong command. Don't run it, or you will break your system. 16.04.x has different package names. And it should be already installed.

Answer (score 0):

The package is `xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe-16.04` 
instead of `xserver-xorg-video-intel` 
and it should be already installed by default.