# Screen tearing on ubuntu gnome (16.04.1)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gnome, graphics, xorg

I've tried distros like Mint C., Mint M., and now I am trying Ubuntu Gnome... I also have problem with screen tearing, for example when I move windows, or watching tearing test on youtube, or scrolling text...

My laptop is asus n56vj, and here is configuration:
[image]

Can you tell me which nvidia drivers sould I use? NVIDIA binary driver or x.org X nouveau driver? I've tried both with same tearing.

EDIT:
lshw -c Video #output

> ```
>    description: VGA compatible controller
>    product: GF108M [GeForce GT 635M]
>    vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
>    physical id: 0
>    bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
>    version: a1
>    width: 64 bits
>    clock: 33MHz
>    capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
>    configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
>    resources: irq:27 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff
>    ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff   *-display
>    description: VGA compatible controller
>    product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
>    vendor: Intel Corporation
>    physical id: 2
>    bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
>    version: 09
>    width: 64 bits
>    clock: 33MHz
>    capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
>    configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
>    resources: irq:28 memory:f7400000-f77fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) WARNING: output may be
> ```

Comment: You don't have any NVIDIA drivers, so you it will not work in your laptop. Try [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/667466/screen-tearing-in-ubuntu-with-nvidia-intel-graphics/668590#668590)

Comment: yes I do ... i do not know why ubuntu don't detect it. :/

Comment: What to detect? NVIDIA? Your laptop has no NVIDIA driver, it's Intel. Go to update-manager, Additional drivers tab, look if there is proprietary drivers for your laptop.

Comment: sorry I bad read your answer .. in driver manager I have this options:
1. nvidia binary driver (375 - proprietary, tested)
2. nvidia legacy binary driver
3. nvidia binary driver
4. x org x server - nouveau ... which I should use ?

Comment: Please output `lshw -c Video` at your question (not comments).

Comment: ok, I updated question and also my last answer, pls check it, thanks

Comment: You have NVIDIA/Intel integrated graphics. Did you follow solution at link I attached at my first comment?

Comment: Yes , I made this file 20-intel.conf with required code and reboot. But they wrote it will work only with bumblebee. Is any driver of my options fine for this?

Comment: Your Intel driver is i915, it's compatible to applied solution. Did it worked?

Comment: Yes tearing stopped I guess, but also I need install nvidia driver, but I don't know which one.

Comment: Try following the order you post. If none of these works, try nouveau.