# I cant login anymore after adding package

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, login, bumblebee

I am very new to ubuntu, first week with it in fact.

I have 3 monitors and I was experiencing screen tearing on whichever one i wasnt currently using, so I searched a bit and found this:

[Screen tearing in Ubuntu with Nvidia/Intel graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/667466/screen-tearing-in-ubuntu-with-nvidia-intel-graphics)

It said I needed bumblebee so I went to their website and followed the ubuntu instructions found here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Installation

and entered: `sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus linux-headers-generic`

Then It told me to reboot and I did.

Now when I am in the login screen there are large black borders and the screen is SUPER slow, probably running on intel intergrated graphics or something. Also I cant login, when I enter my password the screen goes black for 2 seconds then takes me back to the login screen.

What do I do? I have extremely few packages installed, more or less a fresh ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

Never mind! I managed to solve it. Through advanced boot settings I managed to give myself root access and purge the extension I added and it solved my problem!

I should think twice next time I need a solution, I still have such a windows way of thinking.